# My images are coming as numbers

Tags: angular, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using SQLite Studio and I've added some images to it, I used PNG and BMP image, however in my project instead of receiving the image I'm getting numbers like HEX: "42 4d 5e b3 00 00 00 00 00 8a 00 ..." Could someone help me in what would that be? I did not post my code because I do not believe the problem is in it, but in case I need to edit it and add it. I'm using Ionic 3.

Produto.ts

```
export interface Produto {
nom_produto: string;
nom_subcategoria: string;
desc_produto: string;
val_produto: number;
desc_desconto: string;
desc_experiencia: string;
img_produto: Blob;
}

export interface Produtosubcategoria {
nom_produto: string;
desc_produto: string;
val_produto: number;
desc_desconto: string;
desc_experiencia: string;
img_produto: Blob;
}
```

Database.TS

```
getProdutosCategoria(pcategoria: number){

return new Promise<Produto[]>((resolve, reject) => { 

  let sql = "SELECT PR.IMG_PRODUTO, PR.NOM_PRODUTO, SC.NOM_SUBCATEGORIA, PR.DESC_PRODUTO, PR.VAL_PRODUTO, PR.DESC_DESCONTO, PR.DESC_EXPERIENCIA " + 
            "FROM TB_PRODUTO PR " +
            "     INNER JOIN TB_SUBCATEGORIA SC " +
            "        ON SC.ID = PR.SUBCATEGORIA_ID " +
            "WHERE SC.CATEGORIA_ID = " + pcategoria;
  console.log(sql);          
  this.executeQuery(sql).then(data => {
    let products = [];
    data.forEach(function (row) {
      let product: Produto = {img_produto: row[0], nom_produto: row[1], nom_subcategoria: row[2],desc_produto: row[3],val_produto: row[4], desc_desconto: row[5], desc_experiencia: row[6]}
      products.push(product);
    });
    resolve(products);

  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });

});

 }
```

getProdutosSubcategoria(psubcategoria: number){

```
return new Promise<Produtosubcategoria[]>((resolve, reject) => { 

  let sql = "SELECT IMG_PRODUTO, NOM_PRODUTO, DESC_PRODUTO, VAL_PRODUTO, 
     DESC_DESCONTO, DESC_EXPERIENCIA  FROM TB_PRODUTO WHERE 
   SUBCATEGORIA_ID=" + 
      psubcategoria;
    this.executeQuery(sql).then(data => {

    let products = [];
    data.forEach(function (row) {
      let product: Produtosubcategoria = { img_produto: row[0], nom_produto: 
   row[1], desc_produto: row[2],val_produto: row[3], desc_desconto: row[4], 
    desc_experiencia: row[5]}
      console.log(product);
      products.push(product);
    });
    resolve(products);

  }).catch(error => {
    console.log("não tem subcategoria");
    console.log(error);

  });

});
```

}

Home.TS

```
     selecionaprodutoscategoria(pcategoria: number) {
      this.db.getProdutosCategoria(pcategoria)
       .then(data => this.produtos = data)
       .catch(error => console.log('Something want wrong!'));
    }

         selecionaprodutossubcategoria(psubcategoria: number) {
        this.db.getProdutosSubcategoria(psubcategoria)
       .then(data => this.produtossubcategoria = data)
       .catch(error => console.log('Something want wrong!'));
      }
```

Home.HTML

```
      <ion-item no-lines *ngFor="let produto of produtos"  
      (click)="querocomprar(produto)" no-padding>

      <ion-thumbnail item-start class="imgast">
      {{produto.img_produto}}
           </ion-thumbnail>
```

Comment: Plz share your code relating to how you store data.

Comment: (just so you know: `42 4D` is an 8 byte BMP image signature)

Comment: @Aleksey Solovey  i dont understand

Comment: Someone help me?

Comment: `42 4D` is the magic number signature for BMP files. For more information, see [List of file signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures).